# CSS3 transform on hover

Tags: html, css, compass-sass

I'm currently trying to do a transform (rotateY) on an A element, that have already been animated in CSS.

To sum up : the first animation happens when the user scroll to this block, I had a "show" class, which launch a css animation. This works nice. On a second time, when the .show element is hover, I make him rotate. That second animation, as you can see, is buggy. It flickers, and don't work as expected.

Here's the CSS (Sass / Compass) part :

```
li
    width: 23%
    float: left
    background: top center url('../img/bgHexa.png') no-repeat
    &+li
        margin-left: 2.5%

    & > a
        background: url('../img/pictosHome.png') 65px 60px no-repeat
        width: 100%
        display: block
        height: 220px
        opacity: 0
        position: relative
        top: 90px
        +transform(rotateY(135deg))
        +transition(all 0.6s ease-in-out)
        &.show
            top: 0
            opacity: 1
            +transform(rotateY(0))
            &.hover             
                +transform(rotateY(180deg))
```

The JS part :

```
if( app.toTop >= $('#prezComp ul').offset().top- app.height/2){

            var nb = 0;
            var int = setInterval( function(){

                var el = $('#prezComp .picto').eq(nb);
                el.addClass('show');
                nb++;
                if( nb > 4) {
                    clearInterval(int);
            }
            }, 300);

        }
```

I tried many HTML hacks, I tried with JS, it doesn't work better...

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: code example would help

Comment: Click on the link, all the code is here.

Comment: @enguerranws You should include the code you are having issues with, as per #2 of what is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO. This way if somebody else ever has the same question they can easily find the answer even if the linked page is ever removed.

Comment: I did it, thank you for noticing.

Comment: Show us where you are adding and removing the 'show' class. I dont want to scan through your code.

Comment: doesn't ease-in-out work with :hover?

Comment: ease-in-out works with hover. Actually, all easing effects works on all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse hover is not happing at the time ,Try this code:

**CSS**:

```
#prezComp li {   //style.css:558
width: 23%;
float: left;
position: relative;
z-index: 100000;
background: top center url("../img/bgHexa.png") no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: Mouse hover is not happening ,that why i gave the z-index property. Welcome

Comment: Ok, but, as I'm over the element why isn't hover happening ?

Comment: Because there was another element above it.